# Extend angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

In the current project that I'm working, I have a controller which takes care of operations made on a Grid. Like delete Edit add new row initialize validation and so on. Every thing was fine at the beginning but as the operations increased the file turned in to very long file and It stared to be hard to find stuff and work. I will add a sample code below which will describe my question.

My question: Is is there a way to extend controller into multiple files? Or is there a better way to solve my problem?

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['mainControllers']);
```

**gridCntrl**

```
mainControllers.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ( $scope) {
  $scope.init = function () {
    alert('I am initialized');
       };
  $scope.click = function () {
    alert('I am clicked');
       };

}]);
```

To be more clear is there a way to separate the $scope.init and $scope.click under the same controller but in separate files? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you have lots of logic in controller. Try moving in to services instead.

Comment: That's right but is it possible to add the grid controller scope in the definition of the service? I know that I can access it buy getting it from element but can we add it in the definition as a parameter?

Comment: yes, you can create separate file (common_utils.js) and call this in index.html. there you can create method with scope parameter( to move common functionality). this method can be called from your controller.

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment I know that we could use an approach like access scope using something like this: angular.element($("#mainAppWindow")).scope() in a separate file. But my question is can we extend the controller in another file?

Comment: you should use a service for functionality implementation, pass the params to function if need be and keep service independent and testable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you should evaluate why your controller is so big.

Controllers should just define the ViewModel and marshal data between ViewModel and Model.

If you have business logic, move it out to a service.

Otherwise, if you have independent areas of functionality, break it into multiple controllers. Don't be afraid to create controllers.

Say, you have an app with a Control Panel that defines some configuration, the Main View, and other parts (like UserProfile). Although they may always be displayed side-by-side in the UI (and in fact, by the same View), Control Panel UI logic (what gets shown/enabled/added when user interacts with it) should be encapsulated in the controlPanelController and the main app interaction in one or multiple other controllers.

So, you could do:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <div ng-controller="controlPanelCtrl" ng-include="'partial/controlpanel'"></div>
   <div ng-controller="mainViewCtrl" ng-include="'partial/mainview'"></div>
   <div ng-if="isUserLoggedIn()" ng-controller="profileInfoCtrl ng-include="'partials/profile'"></div>
</div>

.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, ConfigSvc, UserService){
  $scope.config = ConfigSvc;
  $scope.isUserLoggedIn = UserService.isLoggedIn;
})

.controller("controlPanelCtrl", function($scope, ConfigSvc){
  $scope.config = ConfigSvc;
  $scope.changeColor = function(color){ ConfigSvc.color = color; };
})

.controller("mainViewCtrl", function($scope, ConfigSvc){
  $scope.color = ConfigSvc.color;
})
```

The broader point is, break the controller into multiple controllers, rather than one controller that is defined in multiple files.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect guide for me to follow I will make the changes according to your suggestions.